# docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for rhel7/rhel

Tags: docker, rhel, rhel7

My docker

[image]

I found this cheatsheet from internet: https://design.jboss.org/redhatdeveloper/marketing/docker_cheatsheet/cheatsheet/images/docker_cheatsheet_r3v2.pdf

I catch error

```
C:\Users\Administrator>docker run -it rhel7/rhel bash
Unable to find image 'rhel7/rhel:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for rhel7/rhel, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.

C:\Users\Administrator>
```

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

Well, this error means that the docker image you are trying to pull is private. Only logged user with permissions may pull the image. You may use the command `docker login` in order to login to docker hub, but if your user does not have the permissions, it will fail anyway.

Comment: Can you give me more specific information about the site to login? Seemly it is not docker hub registry, it is something related RedHat.

Comment: @DoNhuVy you need to login into docker hub using 
`docker login -u username -p password`

Answer (score 0):

This document seems to be an internal document of Red Hat. REHL is not a community distribution and there's no image for it in docker hub. You need to use one of the [CentOS images](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos) instead or try other GNU/Linux distros such as [Ubuntu](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu) or [Debian](https://hub.docker.com/_/debian).

Answer (score 0):

One of the universal error might not be login, you are probably pulling an image that is not in your local machine, or in the community docker hub. go to the dockerhub online and check if such image exist. If it does, then it definitely Login. These are the only possible issues one can face.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was an error in command.
I have tried to execute this:

```
sudo docker run -dit --name ${CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG} -p "443:443" -p "8050:8050" -p "8069:8069" -p "8052:8052" -p "3306:3306" -p "5432:5432" -p "9003:9003" linux
```

This param **${CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG}** was not identified.

It looks wierd because the output is not telling the param is not recognized but this:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for 443, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
```